# Code Highlighter Inserts illegal Characters

Tags: java

I'm using this online highlighter: http://www.planetb.ca/syntax-highlight-word
to copy my code to a word document. However, when I copy back my code from the document to my IDE (JGrasp) I get "error: illegal character: '\u00a0'" If I type out the code manually, I don't get an error. Why is this happening? And how can I fix it?

Comment: can you post both lines of code for before and after. this could be simply a wrong character. usualy you are given the column count for it. you can just type it again. i believe it is just a space but since it's not actually whitespace.

Comment: `'\u00a0'` is a "non-breaking space".  The syntax highlighter probably replaced all the regular spaces in your code with these non-breaking spaces in order to prevent _Word_ from reformatting your code.

Comment: @ Shawn Here is what I put in my code: import java.io.*; and here is a word doc with the code in it: https://ufile.io/3ljjq

Comment: @Shawn if you want me to upload the file another way, just tell me.

Comment: *"how can I fix it?"* Write your code in the IDE, which has syntax highlighting built-in, so there should be no need for an external syntax highlighter. Besides, by not using the IDE, you're missing out on all the other useful features of the IDE. --- If you want to paste highlighted code into Word, write the code in the IDE, copy to highlighter, then copy to Word. There should never be a need to copy from Word.

Comment: @Samurai there was only one line there and it did not give me an error when i copied it to eclipse. but like kevin mentioned just replace all your spaces at lines you are getting the error. i am not sure why but it could be something with JGrasp

Comment: @Shawn I think JGrasp is just a crappy IDE. When I copy and paste my code from the IDE to word, the code looks really messed up. But my teacher prerfers me to use JGrasp. However, is there any IDEs you would recommend for someone learning Java. I don't want the IDE to do too much stuff for me like visual studio.

Comment: @Samurai i personally like ellipse, get the java package. intelij is very famous and arguably better. there is also netbeans that is very solid. but don't get stuck on one IDE try a few and get familiar with few of them. it all depends on your style. try and see what you like. but my suggestion is to start with eclipse. also they all do many things but does not mean you have to use them. focus on the part you need.

Comment: @Shawn Cool. Does ellipse have a dark mode?

Comment: @Samurai yeah you just need to go settings and search theme. also all the other IDEs i mentioned have dark theme as well.